# I'm getting Invalid expression term ":" error if I use <%:%> with VWD2010 Express

Tags: visual-studio, .net-4.0

I'm getting Invalid expression term ":" error if I use <%:%> with VWD2010 Express, which I believe works with .NET4 framework. Only **<%= %>** or **<% = Html.Encode()%>** work. Is there any other configuration to apply or VWD2010 doesn't support that syntax?

**EDIT**

Here's a sample code I'm using

```
<th><% : Html.LabelFor(x=>x.registrationData.OrganizationName) %></th>
<td><% : Model.registrationData.OrganizationName %></td>
```

It works only if I write it this way

```
<th><% = Html.LabelFor(x=>x.registrationData.OrganizationName) %></th>
<td><% = Html.Encode(Model.registrationData.OrganizationName) %></td>
```

Thanks for helping

Comment: I think it should be `<%: ... %>`, not `<% : ... %>`.

Comment: @Anton Gogolev: Thank you very much. In fact, I thought ":" replaced "=" so that space could be added any where (<%=, <% =, <%  =). Now I know that <%: is the syntax and ":" is different from "=". Thanks again

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Is your project [configured to support ASP.NET 4.0](http://www.asp.net/learn/whitepapers/aspnet4#0.2__Toc253429239)?

```
<configuration>
 <system.web>
  <compilation targetFramework="4.0" /> 
 </system.web>
</configuration>
```

And correct syntax is `<%: Model.registrationData.OrganizationName %>`.

Comment: Yes. It's said <compilation debug = "true" targetFramework="4.0">

Comment: @Richard Then how do you use those new code nuggets? Post some code, please.